# Need formula for excel, to subtract the number "9" to each number individually and

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want you to have some fun. I need something specific.

First i must explain what i do. I use a simple codification for product prices at retail store, because i dont want people know the real price for themselves. So i change the original numbers to another subtracting the number 9 for each number.
Normally I manually write down all the prices with this codification for every product.

So.. for example number 10 would be 89. (9-1 = 8) and (9-0 = 9)
Other examples:

1. $128 = 871
2. $75 = 24
3. $236 = 763
4. $9 = 0

Finally i put 2 number nines (9) at the beginning of the codified price also, to confuse people who might think that number could be the price.

So the examples i used before are like this:

1. 99871 (means $128)
2. 9924 (means $75)
3. 99763 (means $236)
4. 990 (means $9)

Remember that i need 2 (two) nines before the real price. The real prices never start with 0 so, the nines at the beginning exist only to confuse people.

Ok. So, now that you understand, here comes the 2nd part.
I have an excel whith hundreds of my products added, with prices, description, etc. And i decided it is time to use a printer and start to print this information from excel. I have a software to do that, but first i need to have the codified prices in the excel also.

The fun part begins when i want to convert the real prices that are already written in my excel document into a new column AUTOMATICALLY. So that way i don´t have to type again all the prices in codified form for the old and new items i add in the future.

Can someone help me with this? Is it even possible?

I tried with =A1-9999 but, it works well with 2 character number only. Because if the real price is 5, i will get 3 nines: 9994(code). And if the price is 234 i will get only 1 nine 9765(code). And it is a condition i need to have the TWO nines at first.

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: The better question is why would you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: after that question, is there a maximum number of characters to the piece?  Are there items worth  $1 000 000, $10 000, or just 100.  Also are there decimals to your prices, or are they always integers?

Comment: @dinotom I just need it. Do i have to explain also that its a family business and there are employees that learned this code?

Please, i need help for doing it not for changing my mind. Thank you.

Comment: @ForwardEd Thanks for answering! Prices normally go from 1 to 4 characters maximum. And i dont use decimals.

Answer (score 0):

I will be using helper cells but you could dump it all into one cell if you want since you are only dealing with 4 characters.

For the purpose of this example, I am assuming your original price list starts in B11.

```
=IFERROR(9-MID($B11,COLUMN(A1),1),"")
```

Place that in D11 and copy to the right three more times so you have it from D11 to G11.  That formula strips off 1 character from your price and subtracts that character from 9.  When you go the next column it repeats itself.  If you do not have that many characters, it will return "".

In C11 you will build your number based on the adjacent 4 columns using this formula:

```
="99"&D11&E11&F11&G11
```

It places 99 in front then adds the numbers from the adjacent 4 columns.

Select cells C11 to G11 and copy and paste downward beside your data column as far as you need to go.

An alternate more concise method would be:

```
=REPT(9,LEN(B11)+2)-B11
```

Comment: if you need it all in a single cell, take the first formal and substitute it into the second equation.  Also change the Column (A1) to 1 then 2 then 3 and finally 4 for each time you past the first equation into the second.

Answer (score 0):

Though you have requested for formula , I am suggesting VBA program which seems to me very convenient.
You have to open VBE and insert a module and copy the program. Change the code lines wherever indicated to suit your requirements for sheets etc.

```
Sub NumberCode()
  Dim c As Range
  Dim LR As Integer
  Dim numProbs As Long
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim s As Integer
  Dim v As Long
  Dim v1 As Long
  Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change as per yr requirement
  numProbs = 0
  LR = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  For Each c In sht.Range("A1:A" & LR).Cells
    s = Len(c)
    v = c.Value
    v1 = 99
    For s = 1 To Len(c)
      v1 = v1 & (9 - Mid(c, s, 1))
    Next
    c.Offset(0, 1).Value = v1
    v1 = 99
    numProbs = numProbs + 1
   Next
  MsgBox "Number coding finished"
End Sub
```

Sample sheet of results is appended below.

[image: Sample sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, though simply:

`=REPT(9,2+LEN(A1))-A1`

seems good to me.

Regards